# Neural Networks in Matlab. Adding large learning patterns

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am new to matlab and I can't find a solution to my problem...

What is the problem?

I have to create a neural network using matlab that will have almost 25k inputs and 10 outputs. There is also 300 patterns to learn.

When I was reading info about neural networks in matlab I saw that all input/learing data are in one matrix. It's ok for xor or something like that small. Then I realized that I would have to create matrix that contains 25 000 * 300 elements (*7,5 mln of integers*).

1) Is there any possibility that I can expand matrix by adding new rows (learning patterns)?

2) or maybe it got something like:

```
learnPatternMatrix1 = [1, 2, 3 , ..., 25 000];
perfectOutputMatrix1 = [1, 2, 3, ... , 10];

network.addPattern(learnPatternMatrix1, perfectOutputMatrix1);
network.addPattern(learnPatternMatrix2, perfectOutputMatrix2);
% ...
network.addPattern(learnPatternMatrix300, perfectOutputMatrix300);
network.learn()?
```

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have an answer to making Matlab deal with that size of matrix. I do have some comments which may be relevant to the problem, however.

Neural networks are, like most machine learning algorithms, unlikely to perform well when there are a large number of features (inputs) compared to the number of data points. Unless you have an order or two magnitude more data points that the 250,000 features you describe, this approach may not work. You seem to have only 300 cases. Even support vector machines, supposedly robust to this problem, are unlikely to perform well under these conditions.

In the case of not enough data for number of features, you can think of it as guaranteed overfitting, as each data point will be uniquely situated and widely separated in feature space.

Have you considered feature reduction? That will solve your Matlab problem, and is likely to improve the performance of your ANN.

Comment: Good news - I can reduce inputs even to 10,000.